# Getting too many indices for array error in numpy.reshape

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a list of a particular size and I have to reshape it to 512, 256.
List contains 97910784 elements which can be split in (747, 512, 256).
I am using this code :

```html
        for i in range(0, 97910784, 131072):

            im_softmax = np.reshape(np.array(im_softmax[0][i:i+131072, 1]), (512, 256))
```

But I am getting "IndexError: too many indices for array". I knew I am getting this error because np.array returns size of (x, ) which np.reshape unable to reshape but I have no clue how to fix this error.

Comment: It's not the `reshape` that's raising the error.  What is `im_softmax`?  A list?  What is the shape of `im_softmax[0]`?  Your indexing assumes it is 2d, but I suspect it is just 1d.

Comment: @hpaulj shape of im_softmax is : (1, 97910784, 2) and it's a list

Comment: A list doesn't have a `shape`, just a `len`.